# Can apple trees be made evergreen?

Tags: fruit-trees, indoors, apples, evergreens

Is it possible for an apple tree to become evergreen under particular conditions?

I'm asking because I've seen an in-door apple tree that for over an year hasn't lost leaves.

Question moved from [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/24258/can-apple-trees-be-made-evergreen) SE.

Comment: I suppose to answer this question, we should know the precise cues for leaf loss in apple trees. Of course, cold seems probable to be one of them, but there are probably others. Some potential ones include drought, day length, the type of light, etc. Drought in and of itself doesn't seem to be a cue, in my experience, though (though maybe combined with other factors, such as the lack of a cold season, it might contribute). I wouldn't expect fruit from an apple tree if you manage to get it to keep its leaves all the time.

Comment: I believe the photoperiod is the major factor for leaf drop (but can't provide references thus a comment). With artificial lightning and heating it should be possible.